# How to customize TextInputLayout when using a Material Design Theme?

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android

I want to customize `TextInputLayout`'s error text color. My app theme is based on one of the `MaterialComponents` themes namely `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar`. I have created a custom text style based on `TextAppearance.Design.Error`, and created a custom style based on `Widget.Design.TextInputLayout` in order to set my `TextInputLayout` components' styles. But the error and label of the EditText are not displayed in the created style.

Here is my code:

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="ErrorText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Error">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/materialRed</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
<style name="TextInputLayoutAppearance" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/ErrorText</item>
</style>
```

And, I have set my `TextInputLayout`'s theme to this custom style:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/usernameWrapper"
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/TextInputLayoutAppearance"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use a custom style like:

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/ErrorTextInputLayout"
            ...>
```

with:

```
  <style name="ErrorTextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/myErrorTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="errorTextColor">@color/text_input_error_selector</item>
  </style>

  <style name="myErrorTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption" >
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
  </style>
```

The `errorTextColor` can be a color or a selector.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorOnError" android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:color="?attr/colorError"/>
</selector>
```

Pay attention to the textSize used.

[image]

You can also use in the layout the **`app:errorTextAppearance`** and **`app:errorTextColor`** attributes:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/myErrorTextAppearance"
    app:errorTextColor="@color/text_input_error_selector"
    ...>
```

Answer (score 1):

style.xml

```
<style name="ErrorText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Error">
    <item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/accentRed</item>
</style>
<style name="EditTextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/lightGrey</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeWidth">0.5dp</item>
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/slightGrey</item>
    <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/ErrorText</item>
</style>
```

Layout.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:hintEnabled="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        style="@style/EditTextInputLayoutStyle">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/emailaddress"
            android:hint="@string/email_username_placeholder"
            android:padding="20dp"
            style="@style/editTextstyle"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: You have not defined the `editTextstyle` anywhere (in `styles.xml`)?

Comment: boxBackgroundColor does not support alpha channel colors. How to go around it?